# Angular Service is injected into controller, but it appears as an empty object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have the following angular service.

```
angular.module('myApp')
.service('StatusService', function StatusService() {
    var statusService= {
        show: 'off',
        on: function() {
            this.show = 'on';
        },
        off: function() {
            this.show = 'off';
        }
    };

    return statusService;
});
```

Which is injected into a controller, and its on function is invoked, like this:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('aController', function (StatusService) {

    StatusService.on(); 
})
```

But I get the following error.

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get this problem if you declared multiple service with the same name in different places, it got confused and will return an {}.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're using a `module.service()` invocation with `module.factory()` implementation when declaring the service. either change the earlier to `module.factory(StatusService)` (which should really be called `StatusServiceFactory`) OR change impl to add interface methods to `StatusService` itself ie:

```
function StatusService(){
this.show='off';
this.on = function(){};
}
module.service('statusService', StatusService);
```

Here's a demo of the above working: http://plnkr.co/edit/r07kPP85oQQKtJYMYOyK?p=preview

Comment: I changed the type of service to a factory, but the same issue is still occurring. I have always used the same implementation, using service('aservice'), and I have been able to use the service to store data. Basically I just want to be able to change the show to 'on' or 'off' using the methods on() and off().